# Incorrect properties displayed from Json

Tags: json, rest, groovy, soapui

I am having an issue when trying to collect data from a json using SOAP UI and groovy scripting. Below is an example json:

```
{
    "regions": [{
        "hotels": [{
                "roomInformation": [{
                    "hotelRoomId": xxx,
                }],
                "regionId": x,
                "hotelId": xxx,                 
                "providerInformation": {
                    "ratePlanCode": "xxx",
                },
                "providerHotelId": 0000001
            },

            {
                "roomInformation": [{
                    "hotelRoomId": xx,
                }],
                "regionId": x,
                "hotelId": xxx,                 
                "providerInformation": {
                    "ratePlanCode": "ggg",
                },
                "providerHotelId": 0000002
            }
        ],
        "errors": null
    }],
    "errors": null
}
```

What I want to do is select the first instance of `providerHotelId` and `ratePlanCode`. To do this I have the groovy script below to tackle this:

```
def alert = com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def response = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Search Test").getProperty("Response").getValue();

def jsonRes = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response);

def providerhotelid = jsonRes.regions.hotels.providerHotelId[0].toString()
def rateplancode = jsonRes.regions.hotels.providerInformation[0].ratePlanCode.toString()

log.info providerhotelid

testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue('providerhotelid', providerhotelid)
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue('rateplancode', rateplancode)
```

This outputs below in my custom properties:

- providerhotelid - [0000001,0000002]
- rateplancode - [xxx]

The above is incorrect because:

1. **providerhotelid** - it displays all provider hotel ids when I only want the first one which should be `0000001`.
2. **rateplancode** - is correct but it displays a [] around it and I want this removed. Same goes for providerhotelid.

So for this example my custom properties should display:

- providerhotelid - 0000001
- rateplancode - xxx

How can this be achieved within my groovy script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need:

```
//Get all the values, falatten them and get the first one
def providerhotelid = jsonRes.regions.hotels.providerHotelId.flatten()[0]
def rateplancode = jsonRes.regions.hotels.providerInformation.ratePlanCode.flatten()[0]

log.info providerhotelid 
log.info rateplancode
```

You can quickly try it online <kbd>[Demo](http://ideone.com/7ObV6r)</kbd>

Comment: Cool, I did it another way but will use your way as much cleaner. Thanks Rao